# What is difference between these two Where conditions?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a project using NHibernate. I wrote a query by QueryOver.

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>();
list<Person> TypeList = new list<Person>();
```

What is difference between these two **Where** conditions?

```
q = q.Where(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.On<Person>(p => p.PersonType).IsNull, Restrictions.On<Person>(p => p.PersonType).IsIn(TypeList)));
```

and

```
q = q.Where(p => p.PersonType == null || p.PersonType.IsIn(TypeList));
```

Comment: One obvious difference is that the second one is a lot easier to read.

Comment: what differences are you getting the results?

Comment: @CodeInChaos : So, When use from first Condition? What is it profit?

Comment: @Matt Ellen  : Result is equal. But I want to know that
 Whether a difference exists between these two?

Comment: If the results are the same then what conclusion do you draw? One is Syntactic sugar one is salt, which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

The second version is more OO, while the first is basically functional programing.

In the first version you create an object that can return true or false for any given Person object. During creation of the object all you are telling it is what to look for (null value for instance) and where (in the propery PersonType in this case).

The second version might actually make you think there's no object to be mentioned (We're talking C#, so everything's an object). All you are doing is sending the body of a function to the Where method.

In both cases the Where method will run the same way - for every person, send it as an argument to the given object. The difference is how the object works. While the delegate/lambda moves the instruction pointer to wherever the method body is stored (not exactly...this is still not assembly, but kind'a), the OO solution starts to check it's internal state to apply a condition (like activating the lambda you sent it to extract PersonType from a Person). It then asks the question you told it to ("IsNull"), and returns the answer.

These are just two ways of saying the same thing, I know (that's why you're getting the same result), **but the difference is where is the control and where is the data**.
The OO version separates the control from the data and hides implementation by working using an interface (you just tell it what you want and where to find the data, but not how to use it to create the answer).
The functional approach asks you to provide the complete implementation and just lets you run (something like: "you handle the data, the extraction, the control and just about what ever you want...You'll probably do it better anyways").

Hope that clears it up